# How to remove String from another String?

Tags: java, string

I want to remove a string from another string, not all the letters.

example: "hello world my name is john"
removing: "ewo"
result: **"hllo rld my name is john"**

my program deletes all the letters that are from removing

```
String text = "hello world my name is john";
    int num = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        String del = ewo;

        String[] delArray = del.split("");

        for (int j = 0; j < delArray.length; j++) {

            text = text.replace(delArray[j], "");
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

My program return: **"hll rld my nam is jhn"**, but that's not what I need

Comment: But... what do you need? The string "ewo" doesn't appear anywhere in "hello world my name is john"

Comment: Why don&amp;#39;t you try `String.valueOf(detail.toString.charAt(position));` to get the value at each position and delete them based on your requirement.

Comment: maybe my question is wrong
but   "hEllo WOrld my name is john" --> i want to delete EWO, the letters from the string may not be next to each other

Comment: @NikolayPavlov Adding expected output would obviously help others.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
String text = "hello world my name is john";
int num = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    String del = ewo;

    String[] delArray = del.split("");

    for (int j = 0; j < delArray.length; j++) {

        text = text.replaceFirst(delArray[j], "");
    }
    System.out.println(text); //output => hll orld my name is john
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your preferred output, I take it you want to replace only the first matching character. Luckily, Java has a method for this.

Replace this line:

`text = text.replace(delArray[j], "");`

With this one:

`text = text.replaceFirst(delArray[j], "");`

And it now only removes the first matching character, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceFirst()` instead of `replace()`.It will remove the first occurrency matching with your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.prinln("hello world my name is john".replace("orld",""));
```

Comment: This code won't even compile, and it also won't do what the OP intends.  Replacing `orld` will target the literal substring `orld`.  But the OP wants to remove each character in `orld`, one at at time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen from the question it is not clear what it is supposed to do. Desired output breaks the rule you have mentioned as it results in `hllo` - `o` was supposed to be remove right?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "hello world my name is john";
    String str2 = "ewo";

    int currentCharIndex = 0;
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : str1.toCharArray()) {
        if (currentCharIndex >= str2.length() || c != str2.charAt(currentCharIndex)) {
            resultBuilder.append(c);
        } else {
            currentCharIndex++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultBuilder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceFirst() or you can use three loops each for removing e, w, and o and use a break statement thereafter.